# What's the best power injection method for addressable LED RGB Strips?

Tags: power-supply, led, led-strip, rgb

I'm currently working on an outdoor LED Strip lighting project, and as I'm not particularly experienced with electronics, I wanted to confirm whether my current plan/components have any issues that I should be aware of before I purchase the components.

**Components** 
[LED Strips](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07TMLXWF2/) 
[Transformer/Power Supply](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07KS4H9JR/) 
[WIFI Controller](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B08239893C/)

**Diagram** (Apologies for how crude it is)
[image: 1]

Firstly, I was wondering if the LED Strips linked above would need to be powered on both ends of the 5m strip, or if powering just one end of the strip would be adequate.

Assuming they only need one connection per strip, would running three 2-Core cables from the power supply work (one for the WIFI Controller, & two for each set of two LED Strips, as shown in the diagram), splitting at the points where they connect to the LED Strips, or would I need to run a separate cable for each connection (for a total of five cables)?

Sorry if that's not explained very well, let me know if you need further clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faOGpH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Do not daisy-chain the ground nor the power through the data cables. Otherwise an excess current will run through these. You cannot tell the current to take the power cables only. It will take all available paths.

**Only ever daisy-chain the single data wire.**

(It's unimportant which end of a strip you connect the power to. Just don't daisy-chain it.)

Comment: Thank you, that make sense, but many of the diagrams for LED power injection online show both the power & ground being daisy-chained between strips (e.g. https://i.imgur.com/NAgZvFD.png) Are these guides simply just wrong, or are they doing something different?

Comment: Yes, those guides are just wrong. The way they wire it there is current from the far end strips running through the near-end strips and thus overloading the tracks on the near-end strips.